# C++'98 - Cast base class to derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, copy-constructor

I have a templated class hierarchy structured as follows:
AbstractClass -> BaseClass -> DerivedClass.

AbstractClass serves as an interface.

I am including my code below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//AbstractClass
template <class T, class K>
class AbstractClass
{
 public:
        virtual void someMethod() const =0;
};

//end AbstractClass




//BaseClass
template <class T>
class BaseClass:AbstractClass<T,int>
{
      public:
             BaseClass();
             BaseClass(const BaseClass<T>&);
             void someMethod() const;

};

  template <class T>
  BaseClass<T>::BaseClass()
  {}

  template <class T> 
  BaseClass<T>::BaseClass(const BaseClass<T>& baseClass)
  {}

  template <class T>
  void BaseClass<T>::someMethod() const
  {}
//end BaseClass




//DerivedClass
template <class T>
class DerivedClass:BaseClass<T>
{
      public:
             DerivedClass();
             //DerivedClass(const DerivedClass<T>&);


};

  template <class T>
  DerivedClass<T>::DerivedClass()
  {}

  /*
  template <class T> 
  DerivedClass<T>::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass<T>& derivedClassClass)
  { BaseClass<T>::BaseClass(derivedClassClass);}
  */


//end DerivedClass







int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BaseClass<double> baseClass;
    DerivedClass<double> derivedClass;

    baseClass.someMethod();

    derivedClass=(DerivedClass<double>)baseClass;




    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I need to cast a BaseClass instance to a DerivedClass instance.
I try to do this by

```
 `derivedClass=(DerivedClass<double>)baseClass;`
```

but I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to `DerivedClass<double>::DerivedClass(BaseClass<double>&)' 
candidates are: DerivedClass<double>::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass<double>&)
```

.

The error occurs both with DerivedClass's copy constructor

```
DerivedClass(const DerivedClass<T>&);
```

implemented and not implemented. In the code above I have commented it in order to make it easeier for you to make test with and without.

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody have a look into it?

I am using dev-cpp 4.9.9.2 and c++'98.

Comment: `derivedClass=(DerivedClass<double>)baseClass` this is not a cast, its an assigment, and a cast. Compiler tells you everything. How do you expect to "build/make" `DerivecClass` from `BaseClass`? It's not defined. Also casts work in the other direction, you can treat `Derived` as `Base`, not the other way around, because there is something missing from `Derived` in `Base`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I missed that. I will tryint and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: IMO you're gonna fail, because something like this indicates serious design issue, so you will have to redesign your code.

Comment: In what sense it indicates a serious design issue? My way of doing this mathes standard practices with build-in c++ types. es: int i; double d; d=double(i); Could you be more precise, please? Thanks.

Comment: What? Since when `double` is a derived type for `int`? Those are two completely unrelated things. Inheritance-based casting and conversion casts are two different things.

Comment: Casting a base into derived could potentially make the derived class contain junk data.  Also, going it the other direction can cause splicing.  Do you mean to do this with references?  Even with references, the code you have currently is going to cause you issues since the base class is not actually a derived class.

Comment: @DavidPeterson This does not happen im my case, as the only difference between derived and base class is in the former some data ordering is performed, in the latter it is not.

Comment: @luk32 Ok, I understand that int and doule are not related by inheritance; however conceptually speaking it's the same kikng of principle. therefore I do not understand why there should be a design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a simple illustrate why casting a base class to a derived class is a problem for the compiler.

```
struct Base
{
   int i;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
   float f;
};

Base b;
b.i = 10;
Derived d = (Derived)b;
```

When you do that, the compiler has no way of figuring out how to initialize the parts of `d` that are not in `b`. For `Derived`, it is just the member data `f`. For other, more complex, derived classes, there can be a lot more data that need to be initialized.

However, if you had:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
   Derived(Base const& b) : Base(b), f(0f) {}
   float f;
};
```

Then you can just use:

```
Base b;
b.i = 10;
Derived d = b;
```

The compiler sees that you have provided a way to construct a `Derived` from a `Base` and is able to use that constructor to construct `d`.

Comment: @geraldCelente I am glad it did.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the error message, the cast isn't casting the object, it's making a copy via the copy constructor. Since you didn't provide a copy constructor that takes a reference to `BaseClass`, it fails.

To make a cast without going through a copy constructor, you need to cast a *pointer* or *reference* to the object, not the object itself. Casting a reference/pointer to a more derived one is only valid if you know that the actual type of the object is what you are casting it to; anything else would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ casting objects is always about pointers which you try to avoid in your main().
You can try the code below for example in your main to see how it should be:

```
BaseClass<double>* baseClass = new BaseClass<double>();
DerivedClass<double>* derivedClass;

baseClass->someMethod();

//derivedClass=(DerivedClass<double>)baseClass;
derivedClass = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass<double>*>(baseClass);


delete baseClass;
return 0;
```

You can find some interesting reading about casting in C++ right here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: This code could cause problems.  Since BaseClass is not necessarily (and indeed in this case) a DerivedClass, I think you are walking into undefined behavior if you attempt to access data from `derivedClass` which is not actually a `DerivedClass` or sub-class of a `DerivedClass`.